# Xero returning a cryptic "Unknown Consumer"

Tags: c#, xero-api, oauth-1.0a

I am getting a very odd error from the Xero `RequestToken` endpoint.

`oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown&oauth_problem_advice=Unknown Consumer (Realm: , Key: )`

I know the Consumer Key provided is correct and have verified the `Authentication: OAuth` header is right, and have verified the signature with a few different OAuth implementations. If I get some known Access Tokens my implementation can call the data endpoints, just not the token ones.

Anyone able to shed some light? I guess the `Realm:` is because I am not specifying a realm, but neither does the Xero SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face same issue. after contact to support team I get the reason for this issue if consumer key is correct then this error can be occur because signature is not correctly generated.